# Yii CMultiFileUpload select multiple files

Tags: php, yii

Got The Answer

To upload multiple file in to the database for registration 
  have tried so many ways to make multiple file upload workable using CMultiFileUpload widget. Already, I have checked and followed below links-

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47665-multiple-file-upload/

Yii multiple file upload

BUT still no luck!!

Error: storing the data but the files are not getting uploaded 
please help
Here is my code:

**In Form**

```
<?php  $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',
        array(
                   'model'=>$model,
                   'attribute' => 'documents',
                   'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png|doc|docx|pdf',
                   'denied'=>'Only doc,docx,pdf and txt are allowed', 
                   'max'=>4,
                   'remove'=>'[x]',
                   'duplicate'=>'Already Selected',

                )
);?>
```

**Controller Code**

```
public function actionRegistration()
    {
        $model=new PatientRegistration;

        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['PatientRegistration']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['PatientRegistration'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                if(isset($_POST['PatientRegistration']))
                {
                    if($filez=$this->uploadMultifile($model,'documents','/Images/'))
                    {
                        $model->documents=implode(",", $filez);
                    }
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['PatientRegistration'];
                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        //  $this->render('registration',array('model'=>$model));
                        $this->redirect(array('/patientregistration/patientview','id'=>$model->register_id));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->render('registration',array('model'=>$model));
    }
    public function uploadMultifile($model,$attr,$path)
    {
        /*
         * path when uploads folder is on site root.
         * $path='/uploads/doc/'
         */
        if($sfile=CUploadedFile::getInstances($model, $attr)){
            foreach ($sfile as $i=>$file){
                // $formatName=time().$i.'.'.$file->getExtensionName();
                $fileName = "{$sfile[$i]}";
                $formatName=time().$i.'_'.$fileName;
                $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.$path.$formatName);
                $ffile[$i]=$formatName;
            }
            return ($ffile);
        }
    }
```

Add in CActiveForm widget

```
'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
```

Hence u can use this code to upload multiple files in yiiframework

Comment: It's best to reply to your own question with the solution you found. Other people might be helped as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest Code for Multiple File Upload in Yii Framework

**code**

**In Controller**

```
  public function actionCreate()

    {
        $model = new Upload;
       echo Yii::app()->basePath.'/Images/';
       if(isset($_POST['Upload']))
        {
    if($filez=$this->uploadMultifile($model,'Document','/Images/'))
   {

   $model->Document=implode(",", $filez);
   }
   $model->attributes=$_POST['Upload'];
    if ($model->save())
            {
               $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->idUpload));
        }
        }
        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model,
         ));

    }
//Function for uploading and saving Multiple files
    public function uploadMultifile ($model,$attr,$path)
    {
    /*
     * path when uploads folder is on site root.
     * $path='/uploads/doc/'
     */
    if($sfile=CUploadedFile::getInstances($model, $attr)){

      foreach ($sfile as $i=>$file){  

        // $formatName=time().$i.'.'.$file->getExtensionName();
        $fileName = "{$sfile[$i]}";
          $formatName=time().$i.'_'.$fileName;
         $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.$path.$formatName);
         $ffile[$i]=$formatName;
         }
        return ($ffile);
       }
     }
```

**In Form**

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'upload-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>


<?php  $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',
  array(
       'model'=>$model,
       'attribute' => 'Document',
       'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png|doc|docx|pdf',
       'denied'=>'Only doc,docx,pdf and txt are allowed', 
       'max'=>4,
       'remove'=>'[x]',
       'duplicate'=>'Already Selected',

       )
        );?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That was all up is for multiple upload - that's nice, but as for multiple select [you can try this yii extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/348/xupload-workflow/)

I hope that this link will help someone, because I was struggling with multiple select files for multiple upload then. Spent lot of time in Google search. Cheers