# Yii framework CMultifileupload not working with enctype

Tags: php, yii

I am uploading multiple files with `CMultifileupload`  but it not posting files with `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'`

Controller.php

```
 public function actionProject_files($pid) {


           $model = new ProjectAttachment;

            if(isset($_POST['ProjectAttachment']) && !empty($_POST['ProjectAttachment'])){

                echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['ProjectAttachment']);die;
           }
           $this->render('upload',array('model'=>$model));exit;


        }
```

upload.php

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'upload-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
       'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',

    ),
)); ?>


<?php  $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',
  array(
       'model'=>$model,
       'attribute' => 'Document',
       'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png|doc|docx|pdf',
       'denied'=>'Only doc,docx,pdf and txt are allowed', 
       'max'=>4,
       'remove'=>'[x]',
       'duplicate'=>'Already Selected',

       )
        );?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

on submitting `$_POST['ProjectAttachment']`.

If i use `$_FILES` then code works

working action

```
public function actionProject_files($pid) {

       $pmodel =  $this->loadModel($pid);    
       $model = new ProjectAttachment;

        if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)){
           echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES['ProjectAttachment']);die;
       }
       $this->render('my',array('pmodel' => $pmodel,'model'=>$model));exit;

       /* $usersModel = new ProjectMembers("searchByProject($id)");

        $usersModel->unsetAttributes();

    }
```

but why `$_POST['ProjectAttachment']` not being posted please help me

Comment: You will get all the details of files in `$_FILES`, while `$_POST` will only contains the details of input, select, radio, checkbox etc. As it is clearly seen that your form tag contains no any other input other than file input, your `$_POST` will not contain data.

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854460/solved-yii-cmultifileupload-select-multiple-files